# importing Oozie workflows into Cloudera Hue with shared groups

Tags: json, workflow, cloudera, oozie, hue

My team does a lot of work staging data from other sources.  I've worked to automate/script this process as much as possible because some of these sources have hundreds of tables to ingest.  My pain point is in sharing my scripted Oozie workflows.

I am able to generate JSON files which are imported into Hue, but the JSON files do not specify what users/groups can read or modify them.  This means I would have to manually go through every workflow and share them.  I may be wrong, but it appears that sharing information is stored in the backend of Hue, not the workflows themselves.

Is it possible to add a key value pair inside of the JSON import file to specify the groups to share with?

or

Am I missing an easier way to bulk share?